Will GetProcAddress be slow if too many DLLs are dynamically loaded, especially some are large?
I'm currently participating in a project in which the DLLs are loosely connected and all functions across them are called by using GetProcAddress.
The director asked us to load nearly all DLLs after the start-up of the program in order to let the users be able to replace/extend modules freely (so at link time, we don't know the address of the external function except interface names). You can regard the whole program as a combination of hundred of plugins.
Since this function takes a string as its parameter, I guess it uses string comparison to find the actually address of a function. If my guess is right, as string operations are generally much slower, I wonder will the call of GetProcAddress be slow when the project becomes large, that is when the amount of DLLs increases (say 100 DLLs) and the size of them becomes large? Especially for some of function that will be called 10,000,000 times in the future? What's the performance of getprocaddress and how many times it is slower than pre-binded functions (address filled at compilation time)?
Or otherwise, is there any other solutions to meet my director's demands?

This might be useful here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/run-time-dynamic-linking

We cannot answer that conclusively. You need to profile. My hunch is that it will be quite negligable but as I wrote this doesn't really mean anything till you measure.

As a comparison point, Linux has switched to hashing all symbols

As a trivial benchmark you could just grab all the symbol names from the DLLs in c:\windows\system32 into a big std::vector and profile the time it takes to find an entry using strcmp plus a loop. You might see a few microseonds for symbols towards the end of the array.

It's a bit unclear to me why the number of times you call the function would be a concern, unless you're dynamically loading and unloading your DLLs between calls all the time you just need to grab the proc address once and then keep the result.

@Cubic Thbis is because that GetProcAddress takes a string as its argument, so I think maybe every time I use it, some string comparisons will be performed.

@NekomiyaKasane yes but functions don't move around after you load them, you only need to call GetProcAddress once per function over the lifetime of your program unless you add/remove DLLs dynamically, not every time you call the function.

Yes, but the point is that you would never call GetProcAddress in a loop. You’d call it once, at startup, and then cache the resulting function pointer. Calling that function pointer would be as fast as any other library call.

@Cubic Okay, I got your point, you're right. Addtional there're 2 more facts I did mentioned in the post.

the DLLs maybe loaded and unloaded, although not too often
there're nearly 1,000 such calls in one binary using getprocaddress.
caching and refreshing them (along with loading/unloading) seems a mess. I'm currently thinking of a table of func pointers and callbacks (for refreshing) to cache & reuse them, is this a correct way? what's the common way for mature projects to do this? Could you please give me some suggestions, thank you!


Why do you need to unload a DLL (before the program ends)? Could you just load all the necessary DLLs on program's startup and only unload at shutdown?

This has now turned into an XY problem. Please edit your question with the actual problem you are solving and why you think loading all these functions on DLL (re)load will be a problem or ask a new one.

Also, even if some DLLs will rarely be used (and thus I suppose you want to load those only once particular need arises), it doesn't make much sense to unload a DLL if there is a possibility this DLL will become needed again at some later time during execution. Loading DLLs is slow. So, instead of unloading, then loading again, then refreshing the pointers, you could just not unload, eliminating the need to refresh the pointers.

@Botje Okay, I'll update the post later.

@heapunderrun This is required by the director aimed to tear the whole program into parts (as DLLs) which the users can rewrite/replace/extend, you can regard the WHOLE program as combination of plugins. I think this is strange but I cannot change the decision. So the DLLs must be aggrated loosely, and be loaded after start up.

Componentization is understandable. But is it required to use so-called run-time linking (via LoadLibrary etc.) or could you use so-called load-time linking (i.e., just linking against the necessary DLLs during build) instead? Also, even with run-time linking, why can't you load all configured plugins at once during startup of the program?

@NekomiyaKasane Most plugin architectures I have seen make the plugin responsible for (un)registering itself with some global datastructure and/or exposing a list of functions addresses to call. Then you don't need GetProcAddress at all!

@heapunderrun Unfortunately run-time linking is required even for the basic modules, everything is required to be replacable. But it's okay to load all configured plugins at once. Unloading library seldom happens, but it must be supported as well. So I'm thinking how to make those frequent function calls across DLL boundaries as fast as possible.

@Botje That sounds great! could you please tell me some project links or docs using the architecture you mentioned? Thank you!

nginx comes to mind, as does apache and the Linux kernel

@NekomiyaKasane "So I'm thinking how to make those frequent function calls across DLL boundaries as fast as possible" - that is why you should be caching the pointer that GetProcAddress() returns.  You call the DLL function via the pointer, and you retrieve the pointer only 1 time per load.  DO NOT call GetProcAddress() every time you want to call a DLL function! Also, if your compiler/linker supports delay-loading, then you don't even need to handle LoadLibrary()+GetProcAddress() yourself, let your compiler's runtime handle everything for you.

@NekomiyaKasane Otherwise, you would have to change the DLL design, like Botje suggested. For instance, by having each DLL export only 1 function that then returns a list/struct of additional function pointers as needed.
